# RStudio not launching in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, rstudio

RStudio was working fine for me till today, but it got closed by me unfortunately when the R studio was running. After that, I have been unable to re launch Rstudio.
I have uninstalled and re-installed R and RStudio, but I am still unable to use Rstudio.

Whenever Rstudio is in Windows, Rstudio launches a small display screen as below.

[image: in windows Rstudio launch small display screen]

What action should i take so that my R studio can start working.
RGUI is working but Rstudio is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem just now.  Deleted the desktop.ini file from c:/Users//AppData/Roaming/RStudio.  Others might chime to say exactly *why* that worked, but it did.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. You rule.